# Do I need to call Initialize() method before computing hash in .NET?

Tags: .net

What are the pros and cons of calling method [`Initialize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.initialize?view=netframework-4.6.1#system-security-cryptography-hashalgorithm-initialize) before computing hash in .NET? For example, do I need to call `sha1.Initialize()` in the following code?:

```
using (var sha1 = new SHA1())
{
    sha1.Initialize();
    return sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
}
```

Comment: When it's described as "Resets the hash algorithm to its initial state." what state do *you* think it's in immediately after creating a new instance and before you make that `Initialize` call, if not the initial state?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - ok, you got me, my example doesn't make a lot of sense :-) Anyway, let's say I have a long living instance of SHA1 class - do I ever need to call the Initialize() method on it? I'm still not sure, what could be the impact of it.